# PhpStorm load set of files based upon current git branch or subproject or context

Tags: git, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm to manage a number of projects, all happening at the same time.

PhpStorm kindly remembers loaded files between projects, so when I go back to Project Foo, all of my most recent files are still open.

However, Project Bar is huge and has a number of sub-projects, many but not all of which are branches in git.

Is there a way to change context or subproject such that all of the files I had open for the Bar Window Widget get saved when I change to Bar Laravel Refactor? And again saves those and reopens my Bar Window Widget files when working on that sub-project?

Even being able to do that based up on the current git branch would be start.

Comment: You can use `Context` functionality (`Tools | Tasks & Contexts`). Also: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Integration+with+an+Issue+Tracking+System+in+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Version+Control+Systems+Support+in+PhpStorm -- maybe you will find some useful and unknown yet stuff for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you use a single PhpStorm project that contains many separate projects or sub-projects of a bigger project.

A possible solution is to create separate PhpStorm projects for each of your sub-projects (based on how they are stored in the VCS repositories, for example). If you need to create another PhpStorm project for your main project you can choose to let it exclude the directories that contain sub-projects (and are handled by different PhpStorm projects). You can do that by right-click on the directory in the `Project` view then `Mark Directory As -> Excluded`. The excluded directories can be managed in the `Preferences` dialog box under the `Directories` page.

The drawback of this solution: you have to work with multiple PhpStorm windows (each project opens in a new window).

---

Another way to group the files and directories is to create Scopes (`Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> Scopes`). A scope defines rules to include and exclude files and directories based on their names and paths. It is not very flexible but it works. The scopes appear in the `Projects` window, in the upper side dropdown box that also contains `Project`, `Project Files`, `Problems` a.s.o.).

This is not exactly what you asked for but it can be used to manage a complex project. When a new scope is selected, only the files and directories it contains are listed in the `Project` window.

---

Something more close to what you need is the `Context` feature. It works hand in hand with the `Task` feature but it can be used separately too. Both can be found in `menu -> Tools -> Tasks & Contexts`.

Open some files you need to work on feature `Foo`. Save the context as `Foo`. Close files, open other files you need to work on feature `Bar`. Save the context as `Bar`. Load the previously saved `Foo` context. It should do what you need.

If you also use `Tasks` then a context can be associated with a task. Switching tasks automatically also switches the associated contexts (and the correct list of files is open).